# Why is alpha blending so expensive?

Tags: opengl, alphablending

From my fledgling experience with OpenGL, I'm seeing performance hits coming from alpha blending especially.  I won't show any code samples because it's not particularly relevant.  I'm just interested in why exactly alpha blending is an expensive measure when fragments are drawn.  Clearly it's an extra operation instead of just writing the fragment shader output to the pixel, but can anyone elaborate on what exactly this operation is?  I know I can sift through official documentation, but I'm looking for a quick straightforward explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha blending needs to `read + compute + write` each pixel instead of being a simple `write`. The formula is

```
new_value = old_value * (1 - alpha) + color * alpha
```

this is of course much more difficult to do than

```
new_value = color
```

Comment: isn't right if you consider the non-alpha-blending as a "read + write"? You gotta read the value from the source!

Comment: @WagnerPatriota: then when using alpha blending the operation is `read+read+write`.